# Unable to link OpenID on Stack Overflow with SourceForge

Tags: bug, openid, login

The SourceForge signon page says I can associate an OpenID with my existing SourceForge account: https://sourceforge.net/account/login.php

1. I enter my currently-signed-in SourceForge account password
2. I select the custom OpenID URL and enter `https://openid.stackexchange.com`
3. I'm redirected to `https://openid.stackexchange.com/account/login?<session key bits>`
4. I enter my openid.stackexchange.com login information there
5. I get the error message:

   > Cannot Complete Login
   >
   > Detected an attempt to send an assertion when the identifier (https://openid.stackexchange.com/) is not owned by the logged in user.

I don't understand what that means.

Comment: I just reproduced this by trying to comment [on this blog post](http://redeye.firstround.com/2012/12/why-first-round-capital-funded-a-lawsuit.html), re-tagged as a (possible) bug.

Comment: Slightly different problem here - not even getting the redirect. SF error, `There was an error using your OpenID.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bug related to error message "identifier not owned by the logged in user"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253698/bug-related-to-error-message-identifier-not-owned-by-the-logged-in-user)

Answer (score 5):

I just tried to do this as well. It appears it's not possible to use Stack Exchange's OpenID in SourceForge without using delegation.

If you want to try delegation though, go to your [open.stackexhange user page](https://openid.stackexchange.com/user#), click "Use your own URL to log in", and serve that HTML snippet somewhere on your own personal site. (I think that's how it works.)