# Bug related to error message "identifier not owned by the logged in user"

Tags: bug, stack-exchange-openid

I tried to register on http://www.commandlinefu.com/users/openid with my Stack Exchange OpenID. It logged me in, but not completely.

The full error message is:

> Detected an attempt to send an assertion when the identifier (https://openid.stackexchange.com/) is not owned by the logged in user.

I don't know where it could come from (CommandLineFu, SE, whatever).
I tried with Firefox & Opera 29, both at home and at work.

If anyone could confirm, we will at least be sure it is not a temporary issue.

Comment: Happens to me as well! (Detected an attempt to send an assertion when the identifier (https://openid.stackexchange.com/) is not owned by the logged in user.)

Comment: Still there one year later. Openid issue ?

Comment: @Mat dunno, but why did you put support tag when you even wrote in the title "bug"? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard because I asked for support, to determine if it was a bug :). But it looks like more of a mislead in using openid urls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It worked !

I did not use the default `https://openid.stackexchange.com/` but the url pointing to your specific id.
In your SE openid profile, click on `Use your own URL to log in` and copy the url matching `openid2.local_id` (Something like https://openid.stackexchange.com/user/UUID).